# Local http/https request via Javascript with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, http, https, esp32

I want to make requests to an esp32 at the clients location (local-network).
The Idea is to control an esp32 via the webbrowser. I want to use PHP for the backend. How can I control the esp32 without using a forwarded port.

My idea was to let a javascript-script make the http call to the local-ip from the esp32 with a simple http server on it. Localy it worked, but I wondered if this is still working if the server is outside of my local network, but I dont have a webserver, so ive uploaded a test file to github pages and tried to access my esp32 via githubpages. But unfortunately the request got blocked:

> Even though the initial HTML page is loaded over a secure HTTPS connection, some resources like images, stylesheets or scripts are being accessed over an insecure HTTP connection. Usage of insecure resources is restricted to strengthen the security of your entire site.
> To resolve this issue, load all resources over a secure HTTPS connection.

Ive installed a basic https server on the esp32: https://techtutorialsx.com/2019/04/07/esp32-https-web-server/

but i got the same error again.The request is made in this code:

```
document.write("Mate");
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open("GET", "https://ip_esp32/", false);

xmlHttp.send(null);
document.write("Try:" + xmlHttp.responseText);
```

How can I make a request with javascript without using Node.js? If this is not possible, can I controll the local esp32 otherwise with PHP?

Comment: Check your browser's network tool while loading the page for any other resources being loaded into it via HTTP. Also check whether that `https://ip_esp32/` request is actually succeeding or not - it's unclear whether it'll work without a FQDN in the URL, or what you've used in terms of a certificate on the server, and whether that's recognised by the client machine where your browser is running. Have you visited the `https://ip_esp32/...` URL directly (i.e. by pasting it in the browser address bar) to see if it is happy with the certificate? We need a bit more info.

Comment: `can I controll the local esp32 otherwise with PHP`, yes, or with nodeJS or any other server-side language, it doesn't really matter. As long as it can make HTTP requests (which they all can) then it's fine. So your browser could send a XHR HTTP request to your webserver, which then makes another HTTP request to the device. Less efficient, but gets round the problem, if you can't sort the SSL out.

Comment: @ADyson Thats a part of my question how can i send a https request via javascript without using node.js.

If the PHP-Server is not in the same network as the esp32 it wont recognize adress from the esp32 unless I forward its port right?

Comment: `If the PHP-Server is not in the same network as the esp32 it wont recognize adress from the esp32 unless I forward its port right`...unless the esp32 is on the public internet, then no. But whether you send the request from client-side JS, nodeJS or PHP, that scenario is the same. If the machine making the request isn't in a network which has a direct route to the server, the request will fail. Of course if you use client-side JS, and it so happens that the machine with the browser on is in the same network, then you might have better luck. I don't know your architecture, though.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for your answers. Iam currently starting to plan the architecture.